# Use copy constructor for "abstract" super class

Tags: c++, oop, tr1

I have a "abstract" super class called RealAlgebraicNumber and two inherited classes called IntervalRepresentation and NumericRepresentation. Both IntervalRepresentation and NumericRepresentation have a copy constructor and they work fine.

I use shared_ptr like this:

```
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<RealAlgebraicNumber> RealAlgebraicNumberPtr;
```

At another part of the programm I want to use the copy constructor for the abstract super class RealAlgeraicNumber:

```
RealAlgebraicPoint RealAlgebraicPoint::conjoin (const RealAlgebraicNumber& N)
{
    vector<RealAlgebraicNumberPtr> v (mNumbers.begin(), mNumbers.end());
    v.push_back(RealAlgebraicNumberPtr(new RealAlgebraicNumber(N)));
    return RealAlgebraicPoint(v);
}
```

I did not define a copy constructor for RealAlgebraicNumber at all. I have no idea what it should do. The compiler is fine with the code, but unfortuantly when I test conjoin like this:

```
vector<RealAlgebraicNumberPtr> v;
v.push_back(RealAlgebraicNumberPtr(new NumericRepresentation(2)));
RealAlgebraicPoint PPP (v);
PPP.print();
PPP = PPP.conjoin (NumericRepresentation(3));
PPP.print();
```

The output is:

( 2 )( 2  null )

And print was defined like this:

```
void RealAlgebraicNumberFactory::print (const RealAlgebraicNumberPtr& A)
{
    IntervalRepresentationPtr irA = std::tr1::dynamic_pointer_cast<IntervalRepresentation> (A);
    NumericRepresentationPtr nrA = std::tr1::dynamic_pointer_cast<NumericRepresentation> (A);
    if (irA != 0)
        cout << irA->Interval();
    else if (nrA != 0)
        cout << static_cast<numeric>(*nrA);
    else
        cout << "null";
}
```

I use a loop to call the static-print function and put the representation between the ( ).

I tryed it the way Cat Plus Plus propused: virtual method in RealAlgebraicNumber,

```
virtual std::tr1::shared_ptr<RealAlgebraicNumber> clone();
```

implementation in e.g. NumericRepresentation

```
RealAlgebraicNumberPtr NumericRepresentation::clone()
{
    return RealAlgebraicNumberPtr(new NumericRepresentation(*this));
}
```

And then used it like this in conjoin:

```
RealAlgebraicPoint RealAlgebraicPoint::conjoin (const RealAlgebraicNumber& N)
{
    vector<RealAlgebraicNumberPtr> v (mNumbers.begin(), mNumbers.end());
    v.push_back(RealAlgebraicNumberPtr(N.clone()));
    return RealAlgebraicPoint(v);
}
```

Now the compiler complains:

```
RealAlgebraicPoint.cpp: In member function 'GiNaC::RealAlgebraicPoint  GiNaC::RealAlgebraicPoint::conjoin(const GiNaC::RealAlgebraicNumber&)':
RealAlgebraicPoint.cpp:66:48: error: passing 'const GiNaC::RealAlgebraicNumber' as 'this' argument of 'virtual std::tr1::shared_ptr<GiNaC::RealAlgebraicNumber> GiNaC::RealAlgebraicNumber::clone()' discards qualifiers
```

I dont get it! Whats wrong?

Edit: Oke its fine! It had something to do with const, and virtual.

Thank you!

Joachim

Comment: What is `RealAlgebraicPoint`?

Comment: Can we simplify this question? You have `class Base;` and `class D1 : public Base; class D2 : public Base;`, and you're asking how to write a copy constructor for `Base`?

Comment: Will you really have both representations of real numbers verying at runtime in the same program?  If not, you could create a templated `RealAlgebraicNumberFactory<T>` and a set of templated operations for example `template<typename T> T conjoin(const T&)` parametrized by your chosen representation.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think it's better to answer using the OP's existing example. It'll be easier for him to grasp the concepts in terms he can relate to, rather than abstract letters that have no meaning.

Comment: @EmileCormier: perhaps, but I was a bit frustrated by the fact that a class withareallylongidentifier only differs in the final few letters and was never defined. It's tedious to read through and reason about mentally. Anyway, looks like CatPlusPlus managed :-)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I should really work on the class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't define a copy ctor, compiler will generate a default one, doing memberwise copy. What you probably want is polymorphic clone, to preserve the type, and call a proper copy ctor. For that, add a new virtual member, e.g. `virtual RealAlgebraicNumber* clone();`, and override it in every subclass to do `return new T(*this);` — then your `conjoin` will look like this:

```
RealAlgebraicPoint RealAlgebraicPoint::conjoin (const RealAlgebraicNumber& N)
{
    vector<RealAlgebraicNumberPtr> v(mNumbers.begin(), mNumbers.end());
    v.push_back(RealAlgebraicNumberPtr(N.clone()));
    return RealAlgebraicPoint(v);
}
```

Comment: Returning a dynamic object somehow seems wrong. Maybe best to return a shared pointer again.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It could return a shared pointer, whatever. The point is, it must be called on the right type, i.e. it must be virtual.